# Configuration Issue For OpenVswitch Version 2.8.1 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: database

I am a new user on Linux platform, I have tried to install *openvswitch 2.8.1* on Ubuntu 16.04; but after installation I am observing below error.

```
root@syed-VirtualBox:/home/syed# ./openvswitch.sh
ovs-vsctl: unix:/usr/local/var/run/openvswitch/db.sock: database connection failed (No such file or directory)
```

I have done below configuration in *openvswitch.sh* file

```
ovsdb-server /usr/local/etc/openvswitch/conf.db \
--remote=punix:/usr/local/var/run/openvswitch/db.sock \
--remote=db:Open_vSwitch,Open_vSwitch,manager_options \
--private-key=db:Open_vSwitch,SSL,private_key \
--certificate=db:Open_vSwitch,SSL,certificate \
--bootstrap-ca-cert=db:Open_vSwitch,SSL,ca_cert --pidfile --detach --log-file

ovs-vsctl --no-wait init
ovs-vswitchd --pidfile --detach
ovs-vsctl show
```

Can anyone help me in resolving this issue ?.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ovs-vsctl needs to connect to ovsdb when it executes, but it seems to be off by default. To start it manually:

```
sudo /usr/share/openvswitch/scripts/ovs-ctl start
```